# Slowly Changing Lookup Cache from BigQuery - Dataflow Python Streaming SDK

Tags: python, streaming, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to follow the design pattern for Slowly Changing Lookup Cache (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1) for a streaming pipeline using the Python SDK for Apache Beam on DataFlow.

Our reference table for the lookup cache sits in BigQuery, and we are able to read and pass it in as a Side Input to the ParDo operation but it does not refresh regardless of how we set up the trigger/windows.

```
class FilterAlertDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element, alertlist):

    print len(alertlist)
    print alertlist

    …  # function logic
```

---

```
alert_input = (p | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=ALERT_QUERY))
                        | ‘alert_side_input’ >> beam.WindowInto(
                            beam.window.GlobalWindows(),
                            trigger=trigger.RepeatedlyTrigger(trigger.AfterWatermark(
                                late=trigger.AfterCount(1)
                            )),
                            accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING
                          )
                       | beam.Map(lambda elem: elem[‘SOMEKEY’])
)

...


main_input | ‘alerts’ >> beam.ParDo(FilterAlertDoFn(), beam.pvalue.AsList(alert_input))
```

---

Based on the I/O page here (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/) it says Python SDK supports streaming for the BigQuery Sink only, does that mean that BQ reads are a bounded source and therefore can’t be refreshed in this method?

Trying to set non-global windows on the source results in an empty PCollection in the Side Input.

---

**UPDATE**:
When trying to implement the strategy suggested by Pablo's answer, the ParDo operation that uses the side input wont run.

There is a single input source that goes to two output's, one of then using the Side Input. The Non-SideInput will still reach it's destination and the SideInput pipeline wont enter the FilterAlertDoFn().

By substituting the side input for a dummy value the pipeline will enter the function. Is it perhaps waiting for a suitable window that doesn't exist?

With the same FilterAlertDoFn() as above, my side_input and call now look like this:

```
def refresh_side_input(_):
   query = 'select col from table'
   client = bigquery.Client(project='gcp-project')
   query_job = client.query(query)

   return query_job.result()


trigger_input = ( p | 'alert_ref_trigger' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
            subscription=known_args.trigger_subscription))


bigquery_side_input = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton((trigger_input
         | beam.WindowInto(beam.window.GlobalWindows(),
                           trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1)),
                           accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
         | beam.Map(refresh_side_input)
        ))

...

# Passing this as side input doesn't work
main_input | 'alerts' >> beam.ParDo(FilterAlertDoFn(), bigquery_side_input)

# Passing dummy variable as side input does work
main_input | 'alerts' >> beam.ParDo(FilterAlertDoFn(), [1])
```

I tried a few different versions of refresh_side_input(), They report the expect result when checking the return inside the function.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I made some minor modifications to Pablo's code, and I get the same behaviour - the DoFn never executes.

In the below example I will see 'in_load_conversion_data' whenever I post to *some_other_topic* but will never see 'in_DoFn' when posting to *some_topic*

```
import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.transforms.window as window

from apache_beam.transforms import trigger
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions


def load_my_conversion_data():
    return {'EURUSD': 1.1, 'USDMXN': 4.4}


def load_conversion_data(_):
    # I will suppose that these are currency conversions. E.g.
    # {'EURUSD': 1.1, 'USDMXN' 20,}
    print 'in_load_conversion_data'
    return load_my_conversion_data()


class ConvertTo(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, target_currency):
        self.target_currency = target_currency

    def process(self, elm, rates):
        print 'in_DoFn'
        elm = elm.attributes
        if elm['currency'] == self.target_currency:
            yield elm
        elif ' % s % s' % (elm['currency'], self.target_currency) in rates:
            rate = rates[' % s % s' % (elm['currency'], self.target_currency)]
            result = {}.update(elm).update({'currency': self.target_currency,
            'value': elm['value']*rate})
             yield result
         else:
             return  # We drop that value


pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

some_topic = 'projects/some_project/topics/some_topic'
some_other_topic = 'projects/some_project/topics/some_other_topic'

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    table_pcv = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton((
      p
      | 'some_other_topic' >>  beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=some_other_topic,  with_attributes=True)
      | 'some_other_window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows(),
                        trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1)),
                        accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
      | beam.Map(load_conversion_data)))


    _ = (p | 'some_topic' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=some_topic)
         | 'some_window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1))
         | beam.ParDo(ConvertTo('USD'), rates=table_pcv))
```

Comment: This question is interesting - I'll try to get back to you with an answer by tomorrow.

Comment: Hey Pablo - any chance you've had a chance to look at this. I'm also interested in it ;-)

Comment: ah yes - sorry about the delay. One sec...

Comment: Hi @hulahoof, were you able to get a solution for it? I am also facing the same issue with python

Answer (score 0):

As you well point out, the Java SDK allows you to use more streaming utilites such as timers and state. These utilities help the implementation of pipelines like these.

The Python SDK lacks some of these utilities, and specifically timers. For that reason, we need to use a hack, where the reload of the side input can be triggered by inserting messages into our `some_other_topic` in PubSub.

This also means that you have to manually perform a lookup into BigQuery. You can probably use the `apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools.BigQueryWrapper` class to perform lookups directly into BigQuery.

Here is an example of a pipeline that refreshes some currency conversion data. I haven't tested it, but I'm 90% sure it'll work with only few adjustments. Let me know if this helps.

```js
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

def load_conversion_data(_):
  # I will suppose that these are currency conversions. E.g. 
  # {‘EURUSD’: 1.1, ‘USDMXN’ 20, …}
  return external_service.load_my_conversion_data()

table_pcv = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton((
  p
  | beam.io.gcp.ReadFromPubSub(topic=some_other_topic)
  | WindowInto(window.GlobalWindow(),
               trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1),
               accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
  | beam.Map(load_conversion_data)))


class ConvertTo(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, target_currency):
    self.target_currenct = target_currency

  def process(self, elm, rates):
    if elm[‘currency’] == self.target_currency:
      yield elm
    elif ‘%s%s’ % (elm[‘currency’], self.target_currency) in rates:
      rate = rates[‘%s%s’ % (elm[‘currency’], self.target_currency)]
      result = {}.update(elm).update({‘currency’: self.target_currency,
                                      ‘value’: elm[‘value’]*rate})
      yield result
    else:
      return  # We drop that value


_ = (p 
     | beam.io.gcp.ReadFromPubSub(topic=some_topic)
     | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1))
     | beam.ParDo(ConvertTo(‘USD’), rates=table_pcv))
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me pablo, let me try out the above and let you know if it resolves my issues :)

Comment: Hi Pablo, unfortunately using the approach above my ParDo just wont run - I will update my Question with more details

Comment: Hi @Pablo, I have updated my question both with my attempt at modifying your code for my use and simply running your example (with the few extra needed bits). Can you have a go at running the code in UPDATE 2 and let me know if you observe the same behaviour?

Comment: I believe I'm experiencing the very same issue. @Pablo It would be great to have a reference for this pattern, as it's likely to be a common requirement.

Comment: An easy fix to have the code inside the DoFn execute would be to use the same windowing scheme for both the side input and the main pipeline (i.e. `beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1))`). Would that work for you? I think you should still be able to control the refresh rate with the auxiliar Pub/Sub topic's message frequency. Code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/bb53ec5c9e5032869811d70bab177a2e) but change is minimal...

Comment: A quick update on this: It appears that when I run the pipeline using a `DataflowRunner` rather than a `DirectRunner`, using the same windowing code from @HulaHoof above, the code works as expected (the `DoFn` with the side inputs executes)

Comment: @HulaHoof I'm facing the same issue with Side Inputs in Dataflow, were you able to solve it?